EXCEL: Split comma separated values within a dynamic range
I have a tabel with comma separated values like



A
B




title 1
10,2


title 2
3,4



This is a dynamic range. I need to split the value because i need to search the values in search for a specific value. I used TEXTSPLIT for this, but it doesn't work on a dynamic ranges. TEXTSPLIT only returns the first value if i use a range as the first parameter.
=TEXTSPLIT(B2:B3;",")

this returns



A




10


3



I got this working with the data > Text to columns option, but i need it in a formula.
Ultimately i need to filter the rows and only show a particular row based on a dynamic number. The formula I used:
=IFERROR(INDEX(
    FILTER(B2:B3;
        (IFERROR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(2;B2:B3));FALSE))
    )
;;1);"")

This matches only the first value in the comma separated value. So i tried another formula.
=IFERROR(INDEX(
    FILTER(B2:B3;
        (IFERROR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(2;B2:B3));FALSE))
    )
;;1);"")

This works, only problem is if i search for the number 1, the number 10 also hits.

=FILTER(B1:B5,MAP(B1:B5,LAMBDA(a,OR(VALUE(TEXTSPLIT(a,","))=2))))



Different routes possible, but my take from what you've written down is that you need there to be a certain dynamic number present. You allready got ms365 and a good answer down by another user based on recursion using LAMBDA(). However here are two more options:
=FILTER(B1:B2,1-ISERR(FIND(","&4&",",","&B1:B2&",")))

Another option would be to switch to BETA channel and see if REGEXTEST() is available:
=FILTER(B1:B2,REGEXTEST(B1:B2,"\b"&4&"\b"))



The first solution only works, like my previous problem, when the comma separated value starts with the number you're searching for.
The second solution didn't work for me.

@BobPikaar, it really doesn't. I just edited in a screenshot where I'd look for the number 4. Are you sure there are no spaces involved in these comma delimited strings?

Thanks @JvdV, that was indeed the case for the first solution. I used the SUBSTITUTE method to get rid of the spaces.

No need, just add the space in with the comma's: =FILTER(B1:B2,1-ISERR(FIND(", "&4&", ",", "&B1:B2&", ")))

This works in both cases (with or without a space): =FILTER(P5:Q6;1-ISERR(FIND(","&3&","; ","&SUBSTITUTE(Q5:Q6;" ";"")&",")))

@BobPikaar, ah you got a mixture of different kind of delimiters. Sure, good alternative.

Thanks @user11222393,
in my case i ended up with the following optimized formula
=IFERROR(INDEX(
    FILTER(A1:B2;
        IFERROR(MAP(B1:B2;LAMBDA(a;OR(VALUE(TEXTSPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(a; " "; "");","))=2)));FALSE)
);;1);"")


You already have several useful answers.
I wanted to share a formula to cope with your TEXTSPLIT limitation to only return the initial value in case you use it on a range of cells, rather than 1 cell:
=LET(b,B1:B2,
     MAKEARRAY(ROWS(b),MAX(LEN(b)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(b,",",""))+1),
        LAMBDA(r,c,
INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(b,r),","),,c))))

You could also use a combination of TEXTJOIN and TEXTSPLIT, but it's not best practice, since this requires all values to be joined as one, to split again, which may easily reach the maximum character limit of TEXTJOIN:
=TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(";",,B1:B2),",",";")

do you see any advantages or unique benefits in your solution compared to the other answers?

@BobPikaar the uniqueness compared to the other replies is that this answer is focussed on spilling the TEXTSPLIT result (as described in the title of your question + start of your question). The other solutions step over the problem by getting to the end result you described you wanted by either using a different logic or using MAP to compare a string to the MAPPED split results. So my answer is not to reach your end goal, but to solve the problem you stated.

Thank for the clarifying. I'm gonna save this one.
